# How to Access Nested JSON data in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have a nested JSON data and it stored in one of our big query table.
Sample JSON data below: I need to get the data from account -> accounts

```
{
  "added": [],
  "data_import": null,
  "removed": [],
  "row_changed": [
    [
      "account",
      0,
      "6b72e3117c",
      [
        [
          **"accounts",
          "1",
          "2"**
        ],
        [
          "expense_account",
          "TEST",
          "TEST2"
        ]
      ]
    ],
    [
      "payment_schedule",
      0,
      "7ba5ca5175",
      [
        [
          "dt",
          "31-03-2023",
          "31-07-2023"
        ],
        [
          "test",
          "$ 0",
          "$ 1"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "updater_reference": null
}
```

I written a query for this but it's returning a NULL value

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 ,col2, col3, 
JSON_VALUE(row_changed, '$.0.3.0') AS col,
FROM bigquery_table,
UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(col3, '$.row_changed')) row_changed
```

The expected out is I should be able to get the data from Accounts with a value of 1 and 2

Comment: Please edit your question and add your data as text not images so it can be easy to help you

Comment: I remove the screenshot and replace it of sample json data

Comment: simple data is great, could you also add the expected output

Comment: I added the expected output. Basically in my JSON I need to get the data from account > accounts with a value of 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

If the position of accounts is always the same then here is a solution using multiple `UNNEST` combined with `WITH OFFSET` and `JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY` :

```
with cte as (
    select '{"added":[],"data_import":null,"removed":[],"row_changed":[["account",0,"6b72e3117c",[["accounts","1","2"],["expense_account","TEST","TEST2"]]],["payment_schedule",0,"7ba5ca5175",[["dt","31-03-2023","31-07-2023"],["test","$ 0","$ 1"]]]],"updater_reference":null}' as col3
)
select account
from cte,
    UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(col3,'$.row_changed')) row_changed WITH OFFSET index_a,
    UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(row_changed,'$')) accounts WITH OFFSET index_b,
    UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(accounts,'$')) account WITH OFFSET index_c
where index_a = 0 and index_b = 3 and index_c = 0;
```

Results :

| account |
| --- |
| ["accounts","1","2"] |